# Redirect to view after API login using Passport

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I added API authentication to my Laravel app using passport. I followed this tutorial:

https://medium.com/techcompose/create-rest-api-in-laravel-with-authentication-using-passport-133a1678a876

Now how do I redirect to a view after the user is been authenticated? I need this to embed my webapp to another portal using single sign on.

This returns the user values:

```
public function details() 
{ 
    $user = Auth::user();
    return response()->json(['success' => $user], $this->successStatus); 
}
```

This tells me the user is unauthorized:

```
public function details() 
{ 
    $user = Auth::user();
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

This is my route:

```
Route::post('details', 'API\UserController@details')->middleware('auth:api');
```

This is my login:

```
public function login(){ 
    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){ 
        $user = Auth::user(); 
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken; 
        return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this-> successStatus); 
    } 
    else{ 
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can validate user after

```
    Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])

    if(Auth::check())
        return redirect()->route('<route_name>');
```